# Custom node editor in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

Im currently making a game on unity, and in the game i want to make quest system to be flexible, as the game world is generated randomly. I also want to make it easy to create quests for myself and possibly modders. So i want to make a menu for creating quests, however i couldnt find any info on how to make node editor window in unity(like shader graph, vfx graph, etc.). How do I do this?

Comment: A Google search for "Unity node editor" turns up four video tutorials, guides for "creating a node based editor in Unity", and github projects that "let you create your own node graph systems in Unity" all on the first page of results. Is it safe to assume you've thoroughly researched this wealth of material already? Which guide are you currently following and where specifically did you get stuck along the way? The more you can tell us about the specific problem you need to solve, the better we can target answers to be useful to you.

Comment: I recommend you build a single quest first, if you haven’t already.

Comment: If you want to open up your game for modding, I'm not sure tying your hands with the Unity editor is the best way to go about it.